# spring batch Multiresourceitemreader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How to know when Multiresourceitemreader is going for the next file while reading multiple files? I need to get the header of each file while reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you use a `FlatFileItemReader` as `MultiResourceItemReader.setDelegate()`:
use `FlatFileItemReader.setSkippedLinesCallback(LineCallbackHandler lineCallbackHandler)` with `FlatFileItemReader.setLineToSkip(1)` to manage first line like an header.
[`LineCallbackHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/LineCallbackHandler.html) interface for handling a line from file. Useful e.g. for header processing.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer. But i don't want to skip any lines. Instead i have to validate the file format based on the header.

Comment: Did you read official doc? skipped lines are passed to LineCallbackHandler, the right place to perform header validation: pair validation with a custom exception throw to stop file processing